# Can a POE switch power devices if a non-POE hub or switch sits between the source and device?

Tags: networking, power-over-ethernet

I want to buy a single POE source and distribute it with cheap network hubs that do not have POE. Will this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. POE will only be supplied to devices that are directly connected to the POE switch, and only by request.

The standard by which this works is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Standard_implementation

Comment: Patch panels are different though?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work -- PoE doesn't carry through additional switches/hubs -- the last switch before the device has to be the PoE switch.  You can safely plug non-PoE devices (such as other switches) into PoE ports, though.

Answer (score -1):

No. First, I hope there are no more [hubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub) out there and [switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) must be POE-capable.

Comment: Just to confirm, it is likely plugging a POE hub into a non-POE hub might destroy it?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but anyway, a non-POE *switch* is not capable of distributing power, so there is no reason in risking damage to your equipment.

Comment: No, plugging a non-POE hub into a POE hub will not destroy it. The POE protocol will only supply power to the devices that request it.

Comment: FYI, we do this all the time - we have several switches in our office after the POE switch. No damage is done to them, and no POE gets through them.